# Constant gravitational acceleration $g$ and energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, free-fall

I've been taught that $g$ is constant for different masses and that if I were to drop a heavy object and a light object from the same height then they would reach the ground at the same instant with the same exact velocity and it used to make sense for me,

However, let's suppose objects (a and b) being stationary at some height if I were to drop them they will reach the ground with different KE magnitudes and thus different velocities, What's wrong here?

[SOLVED]: The point is that they will reach the ground with different KE but not different velocities.

Comment: Why do you think different KE implies different velocity for the two masses?  It would be a good idea to show your calculation so we can point out what's wrong.

Comment: Who cares?  KE is proportional to Mass, like Force is.  This has no bearing on time of flight.

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy is

$$KE=\frac {mv^2}{2}$$

The two masses will reach the ground with the same velocity because they both experience an acceleration of g, but the larger mass will have a greater kinetic energy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Initial energy is given by $mgh$, and final energy $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, and we can cancel mass - mass is irrelevant in the calculation of final velocity here.  Energy by definition is the ability to do work.  Yes, they have different KE, but they have different mass too.  For two objects that are moving at a same velocity, the one of higher mass will have higher KE, since (logically) more work is done to move the heavier object.